# Calling a method from a java servlet

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method that i have in another class. My theory is i can just make a form and make the servlet its called from look for the parameter and if it matches the parameter its looking for, call the method.

The code below doesn't do anything. ShowStatistics is the servlet the form is created,and the utilities.clearcount is the method i'm trying to invoke.

```
String URL2 = "http://localhost:8080/techfore/ShowStatistics";

out.println("<form method=\"GET\" action=\"" + URL2 + "\">");

out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\" Reset the access count\">");
out.println("</form>");

  String button = request.getParameter("button");
  System.out.println(button);

    if (button.equals("Rest the access count")) {
        System.out.println("match");
        Utilities.clearCount(out);
    }
```

Comment: what is the output of System.out.println(button) ?.

Comment: Well, the value of the button is `" Reset the access count"` (with a leading space, and Reset properly spelt), but your code tests if the parameter is `"Rest the access count"`, without leading space, and with a typo in `Reset`. Voting to close for typo.